# i want to place boxes to be near each other using css with space between

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[How they look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnLlk.png)

i need the boxes to be near each other with a bit of space between but it doesn't seem to work, here's my code

HTMl:

```
<div className="RoundBox"></div> 
<div className="RoundBox2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.RoundBox {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1.5px solid grey;
  box-shadow: #e3eaf6;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 3vw;
  float: left;
}

.RoundBox2 {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1.5px solid grey;
  box-shadow: #e3eaf6;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 3vw;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20vw;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a margin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add small amount of `margin-left` and `margin-right` like 2 or 3 pixels to both boxes.

```
.RoundBox {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1.5px solid grey;
  box-shadow: #e3eaf6;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 3vw;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;

}

.RoundBox2 {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1.5px solid grey;
  box-shadow: #e3eaf6;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 3vw;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20vw;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

Comment: The answer by @Muhammedogz is slightly correct but `margin-right` to one box and `margin-left` to another box will cause an alignment issue in the responsive view. You have to give `margin-left` & `margin-right` to both boxes.